# tbody scroll not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have defined a HTML table with thead, tbody and tfoot and also I have given tbody vertical scroll. The scroll is working fine in fire fox but its not active in safari. I googled and found that tbody scroll will not work, is there any alternative for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this is not supported by the CSS specification. Quoting Boris Zbarsky, a leading Mozilla developer:

> Note that the Firefox implementation was removed, because it violated 
>   the CSS2.1 spec, caused compatibility problems for other browsers, and 
>   was buggy to the point that it wasn't worth the effort needed to 
>   maintain it (esp. given the other strikes against it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x:scroll`. It works properly